# There is no script engine for file extension .tmpl

Tags: svn

Im trying to run a post-commit hook script in my Windows7 machine.I get an error saying that "there is no script engine for file extension .tmpl". I am new to Tortoise SVN. Should I download any script engine for this?. I tried changing the file extension to .exe and .bat but still getting the same error. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

.tmpl extention is for the provided templates with SVN hook dir.
You can run hook scripts on windows as batch scripts with .bat extension.

Please write the hook as a batch script , it will resolve the issue .

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using a batch script as post-commit hook. But I Windows throwed the same error "there is no script engine for file extension .bat" right now I have downloaded a setup for running .js files. Now my post-commit.js is getting triggered. But I dont know how to write a script for auto-backup as soon a code is commited to tortoiseSVN. Am I proceeding in the right direction?? I have a shell script which can do the auto backup. But how can I use that?? Please suggest.